# How to Edit a Pic Comment without redirecting to an Edit view page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, model-view-controller

I am building an app for practice,(Instagram replica), and I am having a really hard time getting a feature to work.

What I want to happen is, a user is able to edit or delete their own comments about a picture. I was able to get the delete feature to work, but I am unable to figure out the 'Edit comment' feature. I want the user to be able to edit the comment from within the picture show page. Code is below.

pics_controller.rb

```
class PicsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_pic, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pics = Pic.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @pic = current_user.pics.build
  end

  def create
    @pic = current_user.pics.build(pic_params)

    if @pic.save
      redirect_to @pic, notice: "Your pic has been posted!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @pic.update(pic_params)
      redirect_to @pic, notice: "Awesome! Your Pic was updated!"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    if @pic.destroy
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  def upvote
    @pic.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end

  private

  def pic_params
    params.require(:pic).permit(:title, :description, :image)
  end

  def find_pic
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:id])
  end

  def require_same_user
    if current_user != @pic.user
      flash[:danger] = "You can only edit or delete your own pictures"
      redirect_to root_path
     end
  end
end
```

comments_controller.rb

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:pic_id])
    @comment = @pic.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))

    redirect_to pic_path(@pic)
  end

  def edit
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:pic_id])
    @comment = @pic.comments.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to @pic
  end

  def update
    @comment = @pic.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to @pic
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:pic_id])
    @comment = @pic.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy

    redirect_to pic_path(@pic)
  end

  def show
    @pic = Pic.find(params[:pic_id])
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end

end
```

And here is the (_comment.html.erb) partial being called from the show page

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-header">
   <span class="badge badge-dark"><%= comment.name %></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  </ul>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? && comment[:body].present?  %>
  <p><%= link_to 'Delete Comment', [comment.pic, comment], method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", 
    data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %></p>
  <p><%= link_to 'Edit Comment', edit_pic_comment_url(@pic, comment), class: 'btn btn-primary' %></p>

<% end %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. TIA

Comment: so what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ajaxify for that scenario. The steps will be:

- Create the edit link with `data-remote=true` option. It'll enable the link to hit on the server with a ajax request. Also, add a editable `div`.

`<a href="<%= edit_pic_comment_url(@pic, comment) %>" data-remote="true">Edit</a>
<div id="comment_#{comment.id}_form"></div>`

- In the edit method respond the request using `js`. Like:

  `def edit
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js # actually means: if the client ask for js -> return edit.js
    end 
  end`
- Create `edit.js` file. In there, render the comment `_form.html.erb` on the defined div with ID - `comment_4_form` (Lets assume you're now editing comment with id 4).

It's not elaborated I know. The solution will be much bigger if I elaborate. But you are good to go if you understand the cycle.

Comment: I was looking to do this using Ruby on Rails only. But I do like your input.

Comment: @Tony this solution is for Ruby on Rails. BTW, you can't do this without JS. Ruby/Rails is not sufficient to do what you're asking for. Hope if you explore a bit deeper then you'll understand. :-)

Comment: I see. I need to study up on my JS. I am not that great at it as you can see haha. I'm new to development in general. @Emu